# C# Asp.NET Internal Web App: Copy file from a different local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

My internal web app is on server //tom... but i need to upload a file from server //jerry..

while fileupload.saveas works just great to bring the file locally on //tom, when i try to send it back to //jerry, it tells me that access is denied. I tried to give permissions to //jerry/users to do everything but still nothing.

what is the user/group that a web app resting on //tom would be ?

in my code behind i even tried FIle.Copy (..). file.move etc.. but it tells me that access is denied to that particular file from //jerry...

what can i do ?

PS: when i run the web app locally (localhost), everything works just fine, the problem happens only when i go live...

Comment: This is a permissions issue isn't it?

Comment: it seems like it... if it is a permission issue, what is the user for deployed internal web apps?

Comment: If safe to do so, see what happens if you give the folder you are copying too full permission to everyone

Comment: i tried to give full control to a bunch of users/groups: admins, users, myself... still nothing... there are over 50 groups/users in the list though...

Comment: If your `AppPool` is running under the `Network Service` or `ApplicationPoolIdentity` accounts, it will initiate network requests using the machine account, which would be `tom$`.

Comment: You are copying to a folder. Does that specific folder have permission?

Comment: What version of Windows Server and IIS are you running?

Comment: Also, could you give us the exception that's being thrown?

Comment: the er.Message i get in a try-catch syntax is: access is denied to //jerry/files/file.dbf    and i use II7

Comment: hang on, is the dbf a database file? And is it in use when you try to copy it!? Try to copy a file like a .txt file which isn't open and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a permissions issue.  When you run the app locally, it's most likely running under your account but on the server it usually defaults to the NetworkService account, which probably isn't in the network domain.  You'll likely need to create a domain account to run your application under, either that or impersonate the user's domain account if they have access to the directory.

Comment: i added the NetworkService account to the folder and gave it full permissions and still the same: access denied